# Jquery mobile page load does run javascript until after a page refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile

I included an external `javascript` file on a `jquery` `mobile` page. The `javascript` file modifies some `html` and `css` snippet generated at the server. I've tried putting the `jquery` code that modifies the markup in the following `jquery` `mobile` events -

```
pageinit, pagecreate, pageshow, pagebeforecreate
```

But the script doesn't modify the loaded markup on page load, but on page refresh, it works perfectly. So I'm trying to find a way to make the modification take place before the page renders.
Any suggested will be gratefully valued.

Comment: Show as some basic example of your code, this is not enough for us to help you. Are you anywhere using document ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. I included all the external `javascript` and `css` files on the index page, and it worked well.
This is because `jquery` mobile loads subsequent pages through `ajax`, after loading the first page.